# Bouncy Castle's CMSSignedData PEM produced data causing parsing issues

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pki

I'm trying to wrap PKCS#10 request with PKCS#7/CMS signed object, as there almost no examples on how to do that I've started by wrapping a X.509 instead.
I've used [Bouncy Castel's Example](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedDataGenerator.html), produced the `CMSSignedData` object, decoded it to PEM, and stored it in the file system, and that works.

The issue is that my CA rejects it with "Error Parsing - ASN bad tag value met", also [ASN.1 Editor](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/asn1-editor-wpf-edition.aspx) failed to open the file.

```
private static void generateCMS(X509Certificate signCert, KeyPair signKP, X509Certificate signedCert) {
  CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray("Hello world!".getBytes());
        
  CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
  ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withRSA")
    .setProvider("BC").build(signKP.getPrivate());

  gen.addCertificate(new X509CertificateHolder(signedCert.getEncoded()));
  gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(
    new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
      new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build())
      .build(sha1Signer, signCert));
        
  CMSSignedData sigData = gen.generate(msg, true);
  ContentInfo cmsSignedDataAsASN1 = sigData.toASN1Structure();
  
  JcaPEMWriter writer = new JcaPEMWriter(new FileWriter("test.p7b"));
  writer.writeObject(cmsSignedDataAsASN1);
  writer.close();
}
```

I've noticed something weird, I'm not sure it's related, but when using OpenSSL CMS module for signing certificates the PEM encoded Base 64 always starts with the letters `"MII"`, while my code produced PEM consistently starts with the letters `"MIA"`.

Can someone point me to what I'm missing here?

Comment: *I'm trying to wrap PKCS#10 request with PKCS#7/CMS signed object...* Why? Do any CAs expect that format?

Comment: Yes, Windows CA when using Enrollment Agent, for the Enroll On Behalf Of flow.
Here's a C# example (in the first answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824408/programmatically-communicating-with-a-certificate-authority

Comment: Sorry, I can't find any specs on what particular subset of CMS is expected. One thing you mentioned about "MII" versus "MIA" (you really should look at a multiple of four characters) that made me take a closer look is that the Bouncycastle code generates something called "constructed, indefinite length" encoding, whereas the OpenSSL output is "constructed, definite length". I'll see if there is a way for Bouncycastle to generate that form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, when `org.bouncycastle.asn1.cms.ContentInfo` ASN.1 is being written to an OutputStream it's using [BER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#BER_encoding) encoding, all I had to do is to get the `ASN1Primitive` and instruct the decoder to use [DER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding) instead.

Here's the code:

```
ASN1Primitive cmsSignedDataAsASN1 = cmsSignedDataAsASN1.toASN1Primitive()
sigData.toASN1Structure().toASN1Primitive()
PemObject pemObject = new PemObject("CMS", 
                      cmsSignedDataAsASN1.getEncoded(ASN1Encoding.DER));
PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
pemWriter.writeObject(pemObject);
pemWriter.close();
```